# hibernate batch of insert

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-batch

does the insert of batch in java with hibernate suppose to be created like insert into blocks (name, id) values ('name0', 1),('name1', 2),('name2', 3),('name3', 4)? Why does my application is not creating concatenated inserts to my batch?

this is my hibernate config:

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${iscsi.batch.size.save.blocks}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">25</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>

    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdle">-1</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">30</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">false</prop>
</props>
```

This is my batch code:

```
Session session = null;
Transaction transaction = null;
// Listas usadas para retornar todos os objetos alterados
List<BlockIscsi> listReturn = new ArrayList<BlockIscsi>();
List<BlockIscsi> listSwap = new ArrayList<BlockIscsi>();

Iterator<BlockIscsi> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        session = currentSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        while (i < batchSize && it.hasNext()) {
            BlockIscsi blockIscsi = it.next();
            session.save(blockIscsi);
            listSwap.add(blockIscsi);
            i++;
        }
        session.flush();
        listReturn.addAll(listSwap);
        listSwap = new ArrayList<BlockIscsi>();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error on save blockIscsi: ", e);
        System.out.println("Error on save blockIscsi : " + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NonUniqueObjectException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error on save blockIscsi: ", e);
        System.out.println("Error on save blockIscsi : " + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error on save blockIscsi list : ", e);
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error on save blockIscsi: ", e);
        System.out.println("Error on save blockIscsi: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you confirm that the inserts are not batched? Hibernate logs might not be showing the queries in the format you expect.

Comment: I use <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> and I can see 30 inserts instead of one insert with 30 rows.